# Is there a schema for the JSON Schema draft 4 spec?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Is there a JSON schema that describes the [JSON Schema draft 4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-04) spec?
I.e. a schema that describes the format of the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. And it's [referenced](http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#) in the `$schema` property of JSON schemas:

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
```

From the [documentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-04#page-7):

> The `$schema` keyword is both used as a JSON Schema version identifier and the location of a resource which is itself a JSON Schema, which describes any schema written for this particular version.
>
> This keyword MUST be located at the root of a JSON Schema.  The value of this keyword MUST be a URI [RFC3986] and a valid JSON Reference [json-reference]; this URI MUST be both absolute and normalized.  The resource located at this URI MUST successfully describe itself.  It is RECOMMENDED that schema authors include this keyword in their schemas.